# Test Validator SPL Associated Token Account IncorrectProgramId

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, validator, associated-token-account, solana-test-validator

I'm running a Solana test validator, and I am using `spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account` in a transaction to create an associated token account. The transaction creates correctly, and looks like

```
Transaction {
    signatures: [
        2Y4HFX523xCQqULmxFWCTK3NSUKHBTuHyTjyorDPX4ZDMq12MF1gRVaA7r7DLEZwtXPxdYqekTB7xp6vrwCQUJh7,
    ],
    message: Message {
        header: MessageHeader {
            num_required_signatures: 1,
            num_readonly_signed_accounts: 0,
            num_readonly_unsigned_accounts: 4,
        },
        account_keys: [
            5Xeu3dBDDuiugNvEvo6uN6VvWd37PUTgqFGJPJ32XkmP,
            GNR3TajYA7R3PU6q3SXnecHzgepm999G5TnMaTzKqcoD,
            11111111111111111111111111111111,
            TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA,
            82fDGLz84gDew1qxXVYDcTkEgb146niT6S76xHr1cbYR,
            ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL,
        ],
        recent_blockhash: E4wdTjBTgQh3cyWdX2Uxt97JVTNWr6fKkMyEh6pDKryq,
        instructions: [
            CompiledInstruction {
                program_id_index: 5,
                accounts: [
                    0,
                    1,
                    0,
                    4,
                    2,
                    3,
                ],
                data: [
                    0,
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

However, once I send the transaction to the test validator RPC endpoint, I get the following error:

```
ClientError { request: Some(SendTransaction), kind: RpcError(RpcResponseError { code: -32002, message: "Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: incorrect program id for instruction", data: SendTransactionPreflightFailure(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(InstructionError(0, IncorrectProgramId)), logs: Some(["Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL invoke [1]", "Program log: Create", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]", "Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success", "Program log: Initialize the associated token account", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]", "Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3", "Program log: Error: IncorrectProgramId", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 2392 of 184933 compute units", "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA failed: incorrect program id for instruction", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL consumed 17459 of 200000 compute units", "Program ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL failed: incorrect program id for instruction"]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None }) }) }
```

But this doesn't make any sense to me, since the `program_id_index` is 5, which corresponds to `ATokenGPvbdGVxr1b2hvZbsiqW5xWH25efTNsLJA8knL`, which is the valid program id for the `spl_associated_token_account` program.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Edit: context code is

```
let rpc_client = RpcClient::new(url.clone());
// create fake usdc token
let create_token_tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[
        system_instruction::create_account(
            &alice_pubkey,
            &token_pubkey,
            rpc_client.get_minimum_balance_for_rent_exemption(
                Mint::LEN
            ).await.unwrap(),
            Mint::LEN as u64,
            &spl_token::id(),
        ),
        spl_token::instruction::initialize_mint(
            &spl_token::id(),
            &token_pubkey,
            &alice_pubkey,
            None,
            6,
        ).unwrap(),
    ],
    Some(&alice_pubkey),
    &[&alice, &TOKEN_KEYPAIR],
    rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().await.unwrap()
);
// create fake usdc authority account
let create_account_tx = Transaction::new_signed_with_payer(
    &[
        spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account(
            &alice_pubkey,
            &alice_pubkey,
            &token_pubkey,
        ),
    ],
    Some(&alice_pubkey),
    &[&alice],
    rpc_client.get_latest_blockhash().await.unwrap()
);
println!("{:#?}", create_account_tx);
// fails on the following instruction
rpc_client.send_transaction(&create_account_tx).await.unwrap();
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is typically misleading.  It is actually referring to the program ID of an account's `owner`.  Check that all of your accounts are initialized to the expected program and passed in the correct order

Comment: i've looked at all the owners and it doesn't seem like there's anything wrong but obvs im wrong so

the first account in `account_keys` is controlled by the system program which is expected so that's fine
second account is a pda which i don't rlly know if there's an owner
fifth account is spl fake-usdc mint address for testing, whose owner is the spl token program
the rest of the accounts are programs, which are owned by the bpf loader and are prob fine right? is there anything u see wrong w this

Comment: no, but the fact that you were unable to verify the second account's owner makes it suspect.  That PDA is the ATA to be created, it [must](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/c21b4ae24aada1f766aae374f1ee9a42ae90cb98/associated-token-account/program/src/processor.rs#L108-L110) be owned by the system program

Comment: well the `spl_associated_token_account::instruction::create_associated_token_account` creates the pda for me with `spl_associated_token_account::get_associated_token_address` so I don't ever interface with that myself. How could that be the problem

Comment: u can refer to the context code to see if there's anything wrong w that from first glance